# How to display the selected cell in highlighted state when i come back in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4

I created a custom cell for my table view and for the most part everything seems to be working fine, but when I select one of the rows (which takes me to another UIView), then come back from the subsequent view via the nav controller, the selected cell is not in highlighted state. How to display the selected cell in highlighted state when i come back?

any help is appreciated in advance, thanks.

Comment: If you are not reloadingData in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, the cell should be in highlighted state!

Answer (score 5):

when you are coming back from anotherview make sure that save the selectedCell and then in **viewwillappear** method reloaddata.in `cellforindexpath` write the code of selection style `uitableviewcellselectionstyleblue`

Answer (score 0):

As @sachin said, you should save selected index path

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

and in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

You should check if indexPath is equal to selectedIndexPath, 
but you should be aware that Apple discoureges that kind of behavior in HIG: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html

> In rare cases, a row might remain highlighted when secondary details
>   or controls related to the row item are displayed in the same screen.
>   However, this is not encouraged because it is difficult to display
>   simultaneously a list of choices, a selected item, and related details
>   or controls without creating an uncomfortably crowded layout.